# mysql select field determines order of result set

Tags: mysql, sql, oxid

I am currently experiencing a (to me) very strange behaviour for one of my mysql 5.6 queries.

I have a given system I am trying to optimize. One step is to only select the fields necessary for the next operation.

The given query looks as follows:

```
SELECT oxv_oxcategories_6_fr.*
FROM oxv_oxobject2category_6 AS oxobject2category
  LEFT JOIN oxv_oxcategories_6_fr ON oxv_oxcategories_6_fr.oxid = 
oxobject2category.oxcatnid
WHERE oxobject2category.oxobjectid = '<hashed id>'
  AND oxv_oxcategories_6_fr.oxid IS NOT NULL
  AND (oxv_oxcategories_6_fr.oxactive = 1
       AND oxv_oxcategories_6_fr.oxhidden = '0')
ORDER BY oxobject2category.oxtime
```

I have taken the libery to use more sensible naming in my own query:

```
SELECT
  category_view.*
FROM oxv_oxobject2category_6 category_mapping_view
  LEFT JOIN oxv_oxcategories_6_fr category_view ON category_view.OXID = 
category_mapping_view.OXCATNID
WHERE category_mapping_view.OXOBJECTID = '<hashed id>'
  AND category_view.OXID IS NOT NULL
  AND (category_view.OXACTIVE = 1
       AND category_view.OXHIDDEN = '0')
ORDER BY category_mapping_view.OXTIME
```

As you can see, there is not much difference, only the naming is different. So far, everything works as expected. Now I am trying to only select the values I need. So the query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  category_view.OXID,
  category_view.OXTITLE
FROM oxv_oxobject2category_6 category_mapping_view
  LEFT JOIN oxv_oxcategories_6_fr category_view ON category_view.OXID = 
category_mapping_view.OXCATNID
WHERE category_mapping_view.OXOBJECTID = '<hashed id>'
  AND category_view.OXID IS NOT NULL
  AND (category_view.OXACTIVE = 1
       AND category_view.OXHIDDEN = '0')
ORDER BY category_mapping_view.OXTIME;
```

This also works as expected. But, I also need the field OXPARENTID, so I change the `SELECT` statement to

```
category_view.OXID,
category_view.OXTITLE,
category_view.OXPARENTID
```

Now the order of the items is different and I cannot seem to find out why that is. The new as well as the original query both sort for `OXTIME` without that field being present in the final result set. There are about 10 entries where `OXTIME` is 0, and it is those items that get turned around (ordering-wise) as soon as I query for `OXPARENTID`.

In the original query, `OXPARENTID` is present as well, so why does it make a difference now? I am guessing that there is some sort of ordering logic going on I do not yet know about.

Mind, that both joined tables are actually views, maybe that has something to do with it. Also, `OXID` and `OXPARENTID` are both md5 hashed values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

In order to clarify, I know that the fact that multiple entries have `OXTIME` equal 0 makes it impossible to predict beforehand, which entry will be the top one. However, I still expected the order of the entries to be the same every time I call the query (regardless of what I am  selecting).

One answer (@GordonLinoff) explains, that

> [...] the same query can return the results in different order on different runs

Where does this "randomness" come from?

Comment: ` AND (category_view.OXACTIVE = 1
       AND category_view.OXHIDDEN = '0')` - this is an inner join

Comment: There's no implicit order in sql. You are only ordering by oxtime, so other fields (with same oxtime) will have a random order. Why don't you just add the other fields to your order by?

Comment: @AlexZen unfortunately, currently both systems (old and new) have to return the same results. As much as I would like to, currently I cannot improve that query in regard to its ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ordering is:

```
ORDER BY category_mapping_view.OXTIME;
```

And then you state:

> There are about 10 entries where OXTIME is 0, and it is those items that get turned around (ordering-wise) as soon as I query for OXPARENTID.

What you have are ties in the keys.  The results can be in *any* order -- and the same query can return the results in different order on different runs.  Technically, the ordering in SQL is *unstable*.

You can fix this by including another column in the `ORDER BY` so each row is uniquely defined by the `ORDER BY` keys.  Perhaps that is `OXID`:

```
ORDER BY category_mapping_view.OXTIME, category_view.OXID;
```

By the way, it is "obvious" that sorting in SQL is unstable.  Why?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering to fall back on when the keys are the same.

Comment: thanks for the answer. could you maybe shed some light on how mysql sorts its results? I know this query is far from perfect, but unfortunately I cannot change that ordering. But I was still under the impression, that if I ran the same query multiple times, i would get the same results returned (which is actually what happens). how is it, that mysql might change the ordering from one query to next, even though it is the same query?

Comment: @Micha . . . Sorting is unstable when the keys are the same -- because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You can good "stable sort" to better understand what that means.